# How to use isSavingNonPostEntityChanges in the same scope correctly?

Tags: block-editor

I got this piece of code to refresh a server-side-render automatically. It works! Source: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/discussions/45205#discussioncomment-3933656 But when I run jslint I get the error:

> error  'isSavingNonPostEntityChanges' is already declared in the upper
> scope on line 34 column 20

```
const { isSaving, isSavingNonPostEntityChanges } = useSelect(
        ( select ) => {
            const { isSavingPost, isSavingNonPostEntityChanges } =
                select( editorStore );
            return {
                isSaving: isSavingPost(),
                isSavingNonPostEntityChanges: isSavingNonPostEntityChanges(),
            };
        }
    );
```

Do you have any idea how to solve that? I would rather not use it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the [`no-shadow`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow) rule. The problem is that it doesn't like that you have defined two variables with the same name: `isSavingNonPostEntityChanges` (see code comments below).

```
const { isSaving, isSavingNonPostEntityChanges } = useSelect((select) => { // <-- here
    const { isSavingPost, isSavingNonPostEntityChanges } = select(editorStore); // <-- and here
    return {
        isSaving: isSavingPost(),
        isSavingNonPostEntityChanges: isSavingNonPostEntityChanges(),
    };
});
```

There's nothing technically wrong with using the same name in different scopes like this. There's no actual conflict and your code will work just fine. This rule is just discouraging it because:

> This can cause confusion while reading the code and it’s impossible to access the global variable.

A solution would be giving the properties you're returning a unique name:

```
const { uniqueName, anotherUniqueName } = useSelect((select) => {
    const { isSavingPost, isSavingNonPostEntityChanges } = select(editorStore);
    return {
        uniqueName: isSavingPost(),
        anotherUniqueName: isSavingNonPostEntityChanges(),
    };
});
```

Comment: Ah, that is how it works! Thank you! I will try that later! =)